# How to contact Apple for the Mac store billing support?

Tags: mac-appstore

I've recently registered to the Mac Store and provided the credit card though I didn't plan to buy anything immediately. Some people say that there is an option "no card" when registering, but I didn't know that, so whatever.
After the registration I was charged 2 euros, without any explanations.

I've searched throughout the Apple's website but I cannot find any way to contact the support. I am all the way redirected to some manuals, while the support with the real people seems to be available for the devises' sales only.

All of this is not about the 2 euros, but about the disappointing experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a three step process - with pictures below!

1. Click support in the Quick Links tab
   on the right hand side of the App
   Store app.
2. Click billing in the [web page](http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/)
   that opened as a result of step 1.
3. Feed in all the information and wait
   the 24 hours or so it takes to get
   an initial response.

It is so worth it to ask for a refund or help (especially in your case where you didn't intend to buy yet) - everyone wins in the end as developers and Apple really don't want a sale that ends up with an unsatisfied customer.

The system is not perfect nor is it set up to allow previews of purchases, so no one should feel bad requesting a refund or two. Especially so if the program wasn't explained well or is seriously faulty. Would you want a $ and change if it made someone have a lasting bad impression of the work for which you get paid?

Do feel bad if you find yourself abusing the system or on your 10th refund request with no good reason and just not getting the picture.

[image: App Store Support Link]
[image: Billing Support Form]

Comment: The answer is amazing, thanks! I've sent the question, let's see what they respond.

Answer (score 0):

Try this form: [Mac App Store Customer Service](http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/contact.html?form=account&topic=Mac%20App%20Store%20Account%20and%20Billing)

Answer (score 0):

[Mac App Store Customer Service](http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/contact.html?form=account&topic=Mac%20App%20Store%20Account%20and%20Billing)

In my experience, they do a great job.

Answer (score 0):

[The link](http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/contact.html?form=account&topic=Mac%20App%20Store%20Account%20and%20Billing) has already been given in other answers.
Did you check in the `Purchased`section of the App Store application? If something has been bought, it has to be there and it will be a valuable information to add when filing your complaint, whether there is something or not.

Comment: I did check but it's empty. Seems that I was charged for some service reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you got emailed a receipt from Apple or itunes.com for the charge on your credit card, there is a URL link next to each item on the receipt, entitled "Report a Problem".  Use that link to report a problem.

If you do not get a receipt from Apple or itunes.com after a few days, you may want to have your bank check for some sort of fraudulent activity.  Also make sure you have a properly secure password on your iTunes account.

Comment: I haven't got anything by email but according to the online bank the money went to ITUNES-EURO-LUXEMBOURG :) However a couple of days have passed and what I see in the online bank now is that there is no payment like this anymore. Probably it was just a card check like those Paypal does. The transaction is still pending though.